# Is my work right?

Tags: integration

[image]
Is my work right? And is the last step right?

Comment: why dont you ask the good people who have already helped you with your question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373971/is-this-integral-right?   No need to start a whole new question!

Comment: Anyway I haven't got my satisfied solution.So I feel boring about this question.Because my mother language isn't English, I have a little difficulty to get the ideas exactly. NoW I still can't understand the last step!!

Comment: Do what he said! Also I misread the last bit of your question because the image was so tiny on my phone, sorry. Yes, your last step is wrong.